# How to check if a column contains only empty / NA values?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[image]

Which g-sheet formula can I use to check if a column has only empty or NA values?

Comment: The "column" shown in your post image does not have "only empty or NA values." It has a header: "Competitor." Could you be more specific about your end goal and the exact range to which you want to apply such a formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this formula below:

It returns 1 if cell is NA or blank.

```
=AND(ARRAYFORMULA(ISNA(A2:A) + ISBLANK(A2:A)))
```

[image]

[image]

This checks if an entire column(except for the header) is blank.

Comment: How would you return "TextA" instead of "True and "TextB" instead of false? Simpler way than? `=IF(AND(ARRAYFORMULA(ISNA(A2:A) + ISBLANK(A2:A))), "NEW", "SAME")`

Comment: I think your formula in your comment is the simplest way to do it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on my understanding, you are trying to check if a column or a one-columned-range to downward from a specific cell is consist of only blank or #N/A errors.

I'd solve this by counting 1. all cells, 2. blank cells, and 3. #N/A cells in the range, and comparing 1 vs 2 + 3.

**For 1. all cells**, we can use ROWS([RANGE]). Assuming the Column range as [D2:D], the formula will be `=ROWS(D2:D)`

**For 2. blank cells**, we have a function which count blank. the formula will be `=COUNTBLANK(D2:D)`

**For 3. #N/A cells**, we need to check if each cell is #N/A and count it. The formula will be `=COUNTIF(ARRAYFORMULA(ISNA(D2:D)), TRUE)`

**In conclusion,** the checking formula will be `=ROWS(D2:D) = COUNTIF(ARRAYFORMULA(ISNA(D2:D)),TRUE) + COUNTBLANK(D2:D)`

[image: conclusion]

Of course, if you wanted to check this for a filtered sheet, this method will not be adequate but that was not included in your question and I assumed it's not your situation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple construction:

`=COUNTA(INDEX(IFNA(C:C)))`

[image]

where `C:C` is the column of interest.

If you need one text or another depending if there is any content:

`=IF(COUNTA(INDEX(IFNA(C:C))), "There is some content", "All blanks and #N/As")`